# How trigger a function inside component whenever arguments change in Emnber octane

Tags: ember.js

so i have a parent in controller like this

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default class IndexController extends Controller {
@service firebaseApp;
@service fastboot;
@tracked user =false;

async init(){
 super.init(...arguments);
 if (!this.fastboot.isFastBoot){
  const auth =  await this.firebaseApp.auth();
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
     if(user){
       this.user = true
     } else {
       this.user = false
     }
      })
     }
   }
```

then call a component loadData like this
<LoadData @user={{this.user}}/>

the question is how to execute a function inside component loadData when @user change?

Answer (score 3):

Triggering an action when an argument changes is not that well supported by Ember Octane primitives yet. A common approach is to use either [@ember/render-modifiers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers#emberrender-modifiers) or [ember-render-helpers](https://github.com/buschtoens/ember-render-helpers#ember-render-helpers).

`@ember/render-modifiers` provide a `{{did-update}}` *modifier*.
`ember-render-helpers` provide a `{{did-update}}` *helper*. Both the modifier and the helper except a function as first position argument. That function is executed whenever one of the other positional arguments changes.

`{{did-update}}` modifier is helpful when the function executed needs access to a DOM element. It sets the DOM element, which it is attached to, as an argument on the function when called.

`{{did-update}}` helper is helpful when the function executed does not need access to a DOM element.

```
{{! A Glimmer template }}

{{! did-update helper }}
{{did-update this.loadData @user}}

{{! did-update modifier }}
<div class="loading" {{did-update this.showLoadingSpinner @user}} />
```

The main use case for `{{did-update}}` *modifier* is to ease the migration from classical `@ember/component` to `@glimmer/component`. In nearly all cases a specific modifier containing the logic, which should be executed, itself is a better solution. It provides better reusability, can be tested in isolation and has clear boundaries to the components in which it is used.

The main use case for `{{did-update}}` *helper* is to fill a gap in current Ember Octance programming model. Ember Octance provides an awesome developer experience for derived state thanks to autotracking and native getters. It provides a great experience to modify a DOM element depending on a value. But it does not have great primitives yet to trigger actions like data loading when an argument changes.

The community current experiments with different approaches to fill that gap. It seems to settle on `@use` decorator and resources as proposed by Chris Garret (pzuraq) in [an RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/567) and [in a recent blog post](https://www.pzuraq.com/introducing-use/). It's available for experiments as part of [ember-could-get-used-to-this](https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-could-get-used-to-this#ember-could-get-used-to-this) package.

The `{{did-update}}` helper provided by `ember-render-helpers` is the most established solution to fill that gap until something like *resources* settle in Ember.

Answer (score 2):

In 2022+, you don't really want to be using the render modifiers mentioned in @jelhan's answer -- while they served their purpose for helping migrate old code, they are no longer relevant for new code.

For new code, you'll want to use resources (which jelhan mentioned indirectly towards the bottom of that answer).
The implementation is much further along, and a part of a different library now: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-resources/

You may be thinking, why another library?
Fear not! this concept is getting rolled in to the framework in the *Polaris* edition of Ember, https://emberjs.com/editions/polaris/

There is an RFC for this if you're curious: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/965

But anywho, on 2023-Sept-22,

> <LoadData @user={{this.user}}/>
> the question is how to execute a function inside component loadData when @user change?

I'd like to reframe the question in terms of data, as thinking in reaction to changes can cause performance issues, double renders, etc.

So, most simply, if we pretend we're in `LoadData`, and want to define state based off `@user`, we can use a getter:

```js
class LoadData extends Component {
  get theData() {
    return { theData: this.args.user };
  }
}
```

here, `theData`, is a function of `@user` / `this.args.user`, and will always be up to date when the user argument changes.

I assume this is too simple for what `LoadData` implies is happening within it, but the gist is the same, we want to *derive data*.

This is where resources come in,
you can define your own "resource", which makes a request, and gets loading state for you.

```js
import { resource } from 'ember-resources';
import { TrackedObject } from 'tracked-built-ins';

const LoadMyData = resource(() => {
  const state = new TrackedObject({ isLoading: true });


  fetch('my-data')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => state.value = json)
    .catch(error => state.error = error)
    .finally(() => state.isLoading = false);

  return state;
})
```

and usage would be

```js
import { use } from 'ember-resources';

class LoadData extends Component {
  @use request = LoadMyData;
}
```

And if you want to pass arguments, you can, assuming you only want to use the resource in the JS part of a class component:

```js
import { resource } from 'ember-resources';
import { TrackedObject } from 'tracked-built-ins';

function LoadMyData(urlFn) {
  return resource(() => {
    const state = new TrackedObject({ isLoading: true });

    fetch(urlFn())
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => state.value = json)
      .catch(error => state.error = error)
      .finally(() => state.isLoading = false);

    return state;
  })
}
```

and usage would be

```js
import { use } from 'ember-resources';

class LoadData extends Component {
  @use request = LoadMyData(() => `/users/${this.args.userId}`);
}
```

Now, there is a bit of a caveat, where if you wanted use `LoadMyData` in a template, due to current limitations within the framework, you'd need to change the definition to look something like this:

```js
import { resource, resourceFactory } from 'ember-resources';
import { TrackedObject } from 'tracked-built-ins';

const LoadMyData = resourceFactory((urlFn) => {
  return resource(() => {
    const state = new TrackedObject({ isLoading: true });

    fetch(urlFn())
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => state.value = json)
      .catch(error => state.error = error)
      .finally(() => state.isLoading = false);

    return state;
  })
});
```

otherwise, usage is the exact same.

```js
import { use } from 'ember-resources';

class LoadData extends Component {
  @use request = LoadMyData(() => `/users/${this.args.userId}`);
}
```

or

```
{{#let (LoadMyData "https://url") as |request|}}

{{/let}}
```

There is another library, which wraps ember-resources, which may be of use if you're using ember-data:

- https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources/

You may be interested in some slides of a presentation I gave on this topic:

- emberconf (July, 2023): https://emberconf-2023-resources.pages.dev/50
- emberfest (Sept, 2023): https://emberfest-2023-resources.pages.dev/48

Docs: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-resources/tree/main/docs

The reactivity system, which ember-resources polyfills: https://www.starbeamjs.com/ (not yet available in ember)